# Как правильно использовать YandexMapkit на Flutter, Visual Studio Code?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, flutter, yandexmapkit

Я хочу попробовать использовать MapKit у себя в проекте. По инструкции данной по ссылке https://pub.dev/packages/yandex_mapkit, я создал свой кабинет разработчика и API ключ. Попробовал сделать по примеру который тоже есть в данной ссылке но карта не загружается. Но единственное отличие это то, что у у меня в проекте MainActivity написан на Kotlin, когда в примере он на Java.

Мой android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bookitsalons">
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="bookitsalons"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBUInWkrcYjTOFbrDEiBVWCxgQ3-VybMBU"/>
        

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard
        |screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        >
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
             Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
             screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
             gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
             Flutter's first frame. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Мой Mainactivity.kt:

```
package com.example.bookitsalons

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
protected fun onCreate() {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
MapKitFactory.setApiKey("My-Api-key")
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
}
}
```

YandexMap в проекте:

```
import 'package:yandex_mapkit/yandex_mapkit.dart';

some code

Expanded(child: YandexMap())
```

Возможно я не правильно перевожу Java в Kotlin, или же для него есть отдельный пример. Есть кто знает как можно подключить Yandex Mapkit корректно? Спасибо заранее!

Comment: `Add dependency implementation 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.5.0' and implementation 'com.yandex.android:search:3.5.0' to android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: `protected override fun onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

Answer (score 1):

Код на Kotlin для инициализации карт

```
import com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        MapKitFactory.setApiKey(API_KEY)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }
}
```